# WordPress - List category according to first letter

Tags: php, wordpress

I have checked similar questions in this forum but I can't find any answers that show me exactly how I can do this.

I've set up a WP page template that lists all categories (and their associated posts) alphabetically, in 2 columns. The display is similar to that shown below:

[image: Current display]

The code is working fine.

**However, I want to change the code so that I can pass it a letter (for example, 'A') so that only Categories beginning with the letter 'A' (or whatever letter is chosen) - and their posts - are shown.**

For example, passing the letter 'A' would result in the following display:

[image: Desired display]

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
<?php

// Grab all the categories from the database that have posts.
$categories = get_terms( 'category', 'orderby=name&order=ASC');

// Loop through categories
echo "<div class='new-column'>";

$counter = 0;

foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
   if($counter % 4 == 0 && $counter !=0){
      echo "<div class='new-column'>";
   }

// Display category name
echo '<h2 class="post-title">' . $category->name . '</h2>';
echo '<div class="post-list">';

// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
   'cat' => $category->term_id,
   'order' => 'ASC',
   'orderby' => 'title',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
$query->the_post();

$customfieldvalue = get_post_meta($post->ID, "PDF", true);
?>

<p><a href="<?php echo $customfieldvalue; ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>

<?php

} // End while
} // End if

echo '</div>';

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
$counter++;
if($counter % 4 == 0){
  echo "</div>";
}
} // End foreach

if($counter % 4 != 0){
   echo "</div>";
}

?>
```

My question is, how do I edit the code so that a letter ('A', 'B', 'C' etc) can be passed to the code and have only the Categories beginning with that letter displayed?

UPDATE

It's been suggested that [Lafif Astahdziq's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47840519/listing-custom-taxonomy-terms-by-first-letter-using-name-like-does-not-work-ev#57235299) solution, posted some time ago in answer to another question, is also an appropriate answer to my question.

At a casual glance it may be. However, having read Lafif's answer, I'm afraid I cannot understand how his code works and how I might use it to improve my code and solve my question.

If a particular answer 'works perfectly' but cannot be understood by the individual posing the question, is that a satisfactory outcome?

If I accept Lafif's answer, then I'll have to ask a further question - how do I use Lafif's code?

Finally, I am not trying to deride Lafif's answer in any way. I'm sure it was made with the best of intentions in response to the earlier question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listing custom taxonomy terms by first letter using “name\_like" does not work even after filtering query using “term\_clauses” hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47840519/listing-custom-taxonomy-terms-by-first-letter-using-name-like-does-not-work-ev#57235299) The answer from Lafif Astahdziq works perfectly and does exactly what you want!

Comment: No, this doesn't really answer my question. I'm a beginner as far as PHP goes and Lafif Astahdziq's answer, while it may be technically perfect, is far too abstract for me. I have no idea how to implement it or integrate it into my existing code.

Comment: All you need to do is copy that function exactly as it is into your functions.php. Then you can use `'__first_letter' => $initial_letter` in your `get_terms` args. If you get stuck, let me know. It's actually a really net solution, you should consider  upvoting it when you get it working :)

Comment: FluffyKittten, thanks for encouraging me to persist with Lafif's solution. I managed to get it working - after a couple of visits to WordPress Code Reference. Agreed, it's neat.

Comment: Glad you got it working! What was the problem you were having with it? It worked for me straight away when I put it in my functions.php. I didn't need to change a thing. If you let us know the problem, we can add to the answer to clarify it for other users. I've seen numerous answers to this question and that answer was by far the easiest, cleanest and least intrusive solution - the less you need to do with the actual SQL, the better :)

Comment: Congratulations! I'm glad it worked first off for you. Sadly, my knowledge of PHP is probably not quite as exceptional as yours; I had to double-check the syntax of the get_query_var() and get_terms() functions.

Comment: Is there anything you would suggest adding to that answer so that it helps others, or do it think it was just because you needed to understand the WP functions a bit better? The aim of Stack Overflow is to be a repository of useful questions & answers, If there is anything you think would make that answer more useful in general you can add a comment to it so the information is there for others too :)

Answer (score -1):

You could do a custom query to the Wordpress database, where you send the search letter in the URL.

Where the query would be something like(simplified):

```
$letter = $_GET['firstLetter']; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE cat_name LIKE '" . $letter . "%' ";
```

You can read about the database relations regarding taxonomies [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Taxonomy)

Comment: Thanks, JaKa. I've used your suggestion here to pass parameter (the letter) to my updated script.